# How to send a list of numbers from a web page to server using Ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem with ajax. I want to send an array of integers that is loaded with several checkboxes. The list loads fine, but when you send it to the controller method it becomes null.

Ajax code:

```js
var ids = new Array();
$(".borrarSeleccionados").on('click', function () {
 console.log("el valor de codigos es " + ids);
 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "./BorrarVarios",
     data: {codigos: ids},
 });
});
```

Method code:

```cs
public ActionResult BorrarVarios(long[] codigos)
{
    foreach (int cod in codigos) 
    { 
        var consulta = "DELETE FROM T_INMUEBLES WHERE COD_INMUEBLE = " + cod;
        using (var cmd = cnx.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = consulta;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Listado", "Inmuebles");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of long data type array try with String data type array in action's parameter.

Comment: Not working yet, its still null. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to stringify your values. MVC will convert that back into an IEnumerable for you.

```
var ids = new Array();
$(".borrarSeleccionados").on('click', function () {
 console.log("el valor de codigos es " + ids);
 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "./BorrarVarios",
     data: JSON.stringify({
          codigos: ids
     })
 });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, not working yet, its still null. thanks for your help

Comment: it was missing to put contentType: "application/json", thanks

Answer (score 0):

problem solved, it was necessary to put  contentType: "application/json"

```
 $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "./BorrarVarios",
       contentType: "application/json",
       data: JSON.stringify({
       codigos: ids
       })
  });
```